# three circles in a line with equal spacing

Tags: css, geometry

I have a design which I am trying to replicate in HTML and CSS.

[image]

At this moment, I am able to get this in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lh5m11ya/1/embedded/result/).

I am wondering how I can make the above three circles in a row with equal spacing in each of them in my fiddle as shown exactly in the design.  I tried using,

```
<span class="circle"></span>

.circle:before {
  content: ' \25CF';
  font-size: 200px;
}
```

And,

```
#circle {
    background: #f00;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

But unfortunately, I was not able to get the same design in my above fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the circles with css:

```
.circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And set each of them the relevant color:

```
.circle.purple {
  background: purple;
}
.circle.orange {
  background: orange;
}
.circle.green {
  background: green;
}
```

Here is the fix based on your jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lh5m11ya/3/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to futz with :before. Just set the thing to `display: block;`

```
.circle {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lh5m11ya/2/

Answer (score 0):

here is a flex box based approach: https://jsfiddle.net/z2s8zq72/

put a container class with display flex and some config:

```
.item-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

This jus defines it as a flex display and the direction sets it to display items top to bottom and then aligns everything in the center.

and the circles like:

```
.circle {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.circle.red {
  background: #f00;
}
.circle.green {
  background: green;
}
.circle.blue {
    background: blue;
}
```

and in html:

```
<div id="healthy" class="col-lg-4 item-container">
     <div class="circle blue"></div>
     <h3>title</h3>
     <p>text.</p>

</div>
```